# Calculating Correct Value, but Not Writing Zero to File

Tags: python

I have python calculating a values called `threepex_sym` for multiple cases (called configurations), then writing them to files.  The files are being written to, but it is writing only zero for certain entries instead of the actual value.

Here is the part of the code giving me problems:

```py
for z in range(analysis_configs['zrange_min'], analysis_configs['zrange_max']):
    if(out_confs):
        for k in range(n):
            f1 = open(outdir + "/ThreepJK/z_" + str(z) + "/Threep_conf" + str(x[k]) +
                      "_P3_"+ plus_prefix(P3) + "_Q_" + momentum + "_ins_" + insertion +
                      "_proj_" + projection + ".dat", "a")
            for tau in range(tsink+1):
                #print(threepex_sym[k][z][tau][0])
                f1.write(str(tau) + " " + str(threepex_sym[k][z][tau][0]) +
                                    " " + str(threepJK_Real_Err) +
                                    " " + str(threepex_sym[k][z][tau][1]) +
                                    " " + str(threepJK_Im_Err) + "\n")
            f1.close()
    else:
        pass
```

`tau` and `z` are just parameters. If I uncomment the `print` statement, it returns non-zero values (as it should) for `threepex_sym`, so I know it is being calculated correctly. If relevant the actual values are on the order of `10^-12`.

However a typical file is:

```
0 0.0 1.0803227616891863e-12 0.0 3.891247568549575e-13
1 0.0 1.0803227616891863e-12 0.0 3.891247568549575e-13
2 0.0 1.0803227616891863e-12 0.0 3.891247568549575e-13
3 0.0 1.0803227616891863e-12 0.0 3.891247568549575e-13
4 0.0 1.0803227616891863e-12 0.0 3.891247568549575e-13
5 0.0 1.0803227616891863e-12 0.0 3.891247568549575e-13
6 0.0 1.0803227616891863e-12 0.0 3.891247568549575e-13
7 0.0 1.0803227616891863e-12 0.0 3.891247568549575e-13
8 0.0 1.0803227616891863e-12 0.0 3.891247568549575e-13
9 0.0 1.0803227616891863e-12 0.0 3.891247568549575e-13
10 0.0 1.0803227616891863e-12 0.0 3.891247568549575e-13
```

So the part where it should be writing `threepex_sym` to the file it is instead writing zero. The other part of the write method (the part where it is writing `tau` and `threepJK_*`) are writing correctly.

Comment: So, none of the values should be zero?

Comment: This is kind of hard to understand. Maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How big are `tsink`, `n`, and your zrange? Is it possible you're seeing nonzero printed values from later files, but opening earlier files to check, and it's these earlier ones which have zero values?

Comment: @CrazyChucky It is OK in general if some values are zero, but I do not expect them to be identically zero for all files.

Comment: @Nohman I edited it, is it easier to understand what is going on now?

Comment: @DanGetz - This was (more or less) the problem.  The earlier configurations were the only ones that had the problem and the later didn't.  Seems the problem is fixed now.  Thanks!

Comment: If you solved it, you can post (and even accept) your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem is.  There was an earlier point in the program where a loop was one indentation too far in (and so was inside another loop).